No se imprime bien mi código
He estado haciendo algunos ejercicios para aprender a programar con Python. En este ejercicio se plantea un diccionario y hay que usar los condicionales.
El ejercicio me pide que cuando aparezcan ciertos items dentro de una key, me imprima cierto string.
Este es el diccionario:
person={
    'first_name': 'Asabeneh',
    'last_name': 'Yetayeh',
    'age': 250,
    'country': 'Finland',
    'is_marred': True,
    'skills': ['React','Node','MongoDB','JavaScript','Python'],
    'address': {
        'street': 'Space street',
        'zipcode': '02210'
    }
}

Este es el código que hice:
has_skills_key = 'skills' in person 
if has_skills_key == True:
    if 'JavaScript'and'React' in person['skills']:
        print('He is a frontend developer')
    elif 'Node'and'Python'and'MongoDB' in person['skills']:
        print('He is a backend developer')
    elif 'React'and'Node'and'MongoDB' in person['skills']:
        print('He is a fullstack developer')
    else:
        print('Unknow title')

Los strings del print el ejercicio me los da, pero al momento de modificar el diccionario para que imprima cada uno de los prints, no lo hace correctamente. Es decir, que si modifico el diccionario para que solo quede 'Node', 'React' y 'MongoDB', no se imprime 'He is a fullstack developer', sino que se imprime el primer print donde esta 'React' que es 'He is a frontend developer'.
Si alguien me puede ayudar o decir qué estoy haciendo mal, porque no sé que es lo que sucede.

Tienes un pequeño error en tu lógica, el bloque if/elif está mal diseñado.
Tu estableces la siguiente condición:
if 'JavaScript' and 'React' in person['skills']:

lo que esto significa es:
si estaPalabra y si estaOtraEsteEnEstaLista

estaPalabra se evalua como un booleano, y siempre da true, entonces, mientras la lista contenga a 'React', la condición será evaluada como verdadera.
Para obtener el resultado que esperas, debes usar lo siguiente:
if 'JavaScript' in person['skills'] and 'React' in person['skills']:


Muchas gracias, no me había dado cuenta de eso

Maestro, un placer ayudarte!!!
